# Calling a method inside thread in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Hello below is a method where `fileUpload` method is called and after uploading files i want to delete the `synchronized` object and i did so. and now i have to reload the page by calling `fillRecipients()` method, what is does is it lists all the information from the database and shows in the `listView`. Since i have used the thread it doesnot allow me to put `fillRecipeints` inside the thread but i want it at line no 230[commented below as Line No 230] below
This is my `Synchronize` method:

```
public void synchronize(final String id){
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ViewRecipients.this, "", "Uploading this file...", true);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                           //uploading.setText("uploading started.....");
                           //dialog.show();
                       }
                   });
                mDbHelper.open();
                Cursor cData = mDbHelper.fetchRecipientInfo(id);

                for(cData.moveToFirst();!cData.isAfterLast();cData.moveToNext()){
                    String id = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_recipient_id"));
                    String info = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_info"));
                    String latitude = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_latitude"));
                    String longitude = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_longitude"));
                    ArrayList<String> imagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                        String image = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_image_url" + i));
                        if (image != null) {
                            imagesArray.add(image);
                        }
                    }

                    try {
                        serverResponseCode = uploadFile(imagesArray, info, latitude, longitude, id);
                        if (serverResponseCode==200){
                              mDbHelper.deleteRecipientRecId(id);
//Line NO 230 here i want to add fillRecipients() method
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                cData.close();
                mDbHelper.close();

                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {
                              Toast.makeText(ViewRecipients.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });               
                 }

           }
         }).start();
}
```

This is my fillRecipeints() method:

```
private void fillRecipients(){
    mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllRecipientsInfo();
    if (mCursor==null){
        System.out.println("empty cursor");
    }
    else{
        String [] from = new String[]{MunchaDbAdapter.FLD_RECIPIENT_ID};
        int [] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter recipient = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.recipient_show, mCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(recipient);
    }
}
```

can any body help me?

Comment: Did you tried using Android AsyncTask ?

Comment: Can't we do this way...If i had to change to AsyncTask than i got to change whole my codes

Comment: 1. you want to get all the details from data base.. for this you can use Async task there is no problem.... then in the post execute you can use fillRecipients() method. Actually you are trying to call the thread under the progressdialog right.. so instead of that you can use AsyncTask

Comment: Async Task is painless thread thats it .

Answer (score 0):

```
public void synchronize(final String id) {

        new UploadAsync.execute();

    }


//async class to do task in background and notify UI after completion of task in onPost()
class UploadAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        ProgressDialog dialog = null;
        boolean isUploaded = false;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog.show(ViewRecipients.this, "", "Uploading this file...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
            mDbHelper.open();
            Cursor cData = mDbHelper.fetchRecipientInfo(id);

            for(cData.moveToFirst();!cData.isAfterLast();cData.moveToNext()){
                String id = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_recipient_id"));
                String info = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_info"));
                String latitude = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_latitude"));
                String longitude = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_longitude"));
                ArrayList<String> imagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                    String image = cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("fld_image_url" + i));
                    if (image != null) {
                        imagesArray.add(image);
                    }
                }

                try {
                    serverResponseCode = uploadFile(imagesArray, info, latitude, longitude, id);
                    if (serverResponseCode==200){
                          mDbHelper.deleteRecipientRecId(id);
                          isUploaded = true;
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
            cData.close();
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //close dialog
            if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }


            if(isUploaded){
                Toast.makeText(ViewRecipients.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fillRecipients();
            }
        }

    }

private void fillRecipients() {
        mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllRecipientsInfo();
        if (mCursor == null) {
            System.out.println("empty cursor");
        } else {
            String[] from = new String[] { MunchaDbAdapter.FLD_RECIPIENT_ID };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
            SimpleCursorAdapter recipient = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.recipient_show, mCursor, from, to);
            setListAdapter(recipient);
        }
    }
```